# embedded video does not play in iPad

Tags: html, ipad, video, html5-video

as far as I can tell, I am following the *au courant* practices

```
<video width="960" height="540" poster="path/to/movie.jpg" controls preload>
    <source src="path/to/movie.m4v" type="video/mp4;" />
    <source src="path/to/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4;" />
    <source src="path/to/movie.webm" type="video/webm;" />
    <source src="path/to/movie.ogv" type="video/ogg;" />
    Sorry, your browser has no video playback capabilities
</video>
```

The movie plays in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome. In fact, the movie plays on my iPad as well, when viewed directly, for example, via Dropbox. However, when I view the page using Safari on iPad, I get a fat slash through the play button.

Suggestions?

**update:** simplified the code to bare minimum. Same result. Works in all desktop browsers, but there is a slash through the **play** button on iPad. And yes, the mp4 version of the video opens and plays fine on the iPad directly, that is, when opened from the Dropbox.